# Run a .NET application in docker container after upgrade

Tags: linux, docker, visual-studio, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I recently migrated my .NET 4.6.2 application 2 .NET 7.0 using Microsoft's upgrade assistant and compiling it in Visual Studio 2022. The conversion went smoothly however, it runs as a console application (which is alright). I want to know what are the settings I must do in the project file to be able to make the application run in a Linux docker container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For .NET 7 you have two options:

1. You can use the [button in VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/overview?view=vs-2022#adding-docker-support) which will create a Dockerfile for you and add a launch profile to enable you to debug in a container.
2. If you don't need/want to be able to debug in the container, you can use the new [publish support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/publish-as-container). Configuring that allows you to publish to an Image, no Dockerfile needed.